# How to create a bottom tab bar with complex shapes in react native

Tags: react-native, view, bottomnavigationview, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I would like to achieve a specific view shape for my bottom navigation in my react-native project. It's a rectangle shape with a center circle shape, with the circle a little bit suspended from the rectangle and also intersecting the rectangle. Here is the mockup:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think react native **reanimated** library give you a big help. check this example https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/blob/master/Example/src/AnimatedTabBarExample.js